# When does Microsoft's IE6 Support Expire?

Tags: internet-explorer

I've had a few customers (banks) indicate that the reason their company still standardizes on IE6 is because it's still supported by Microsoft. They will upgrade when Microsoft stops supporting it they will standardize on IE7 or perhaps IE8.

What is the official expiration date for support on IE6?

Comment: Not soon enough, that's for sure

Comment: Banks... groan!

Comment: When Windows XP support ends: 4 August 2014

Comment: April 2014, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has not been released an official expiration date for IE6.

You can see the support lifecycle of [Internet Explorer here.](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifesupsps#Internet_Explorer)

Comment: Argh :( When I looked at that list a while ago, I saw that IE6 on XP SP2 is to be expire 2010-07-13 and already highlighted that date in my calendar... what I didn't notice is that support for IE6 on XP _SP3_ had just started in 2008... probably until 2012 or even longer. Oh dear!

Comment: Yes there is.  IE6 support ends when XP support ends.  08/04/2014. http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=windows+xp+professional&Filter=FilterNO

Answer (score 3):

When Windows XP is no longer supported, which is whenever Microsoft decides to finalize that.

[Windows Life-Cycle Policy](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/lifecycle/default.mspx)

[Lifecycle Supported Service Packs](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifesupsps/)

Comment: Which is April 2014.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC - XP pre SP2 is unsupported.

XP SP2 and XP SP3 are under Microsofts "Extended" support for another few years (until 2012?).  This basically means that you can still raise a Microsoft support call (Premier customers etc) for XP, and by association IE6.

However, MS has published IE8 as a Critical Update on Windows Update and you may struggle to get a fix from Microsoft for any problem you may encounter.  If it turns out to be a bug in IE6 then MS will not be fixing it (security fixes only under Extended support).

Start working on your IE8 rollout plans.  It's stable, renders better than IE7 and is toe-to-toe with FireFox (without the plugins)